# How do I convert a blob to an mp4 video file and upload it to WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, blob, getusermedia

I'm trying to record a video using getUserMedia and send that to WordPress to upload.

The problem is WordPress gives me this error:

`Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons`

I set the type of the blob to `video/mp4`, but when I try to console.log the type of the blob, it says `undefined`, and when I print out the type in PHP of the file I notice it says `application/octet-stream`, so I'm wondering if that's the issue.

Here is my JavaScript, I'm generating the blob in a different part of the application and storing/retrieving it in localStorage:

```js
var formData = new FormData(form.get(0));

formData.append('action', 'hm_share_your_song_submission');
formData.append('email', emailInput.val())

let videoBlob = localStorage.getItem('videoBlob');
let videoFile = new File([videoBlob], 'video-name.mp4', { lastModified: new Date().getTime(), type: 'video/mp4' });

if(videoBlob !== null) {
  formData.append('recorded-video-file', videoFile);
  console.log(videoBlob.type);
  localStorage.removeItem('videoBlob');
}

$.ajax({
  url: ajax_url,
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

And then in PHP I have this:

```
$file = !empty($_FILES['video-file']['name']) ? $_FILES['video-file'] : ((!empty($_FILES['recorded-video-file']['name'])) ? $_FILES['recorded-video-file'] : null);
$upload_overrides = ['test_form' => false];
$file = wp_handle_upload($file, $upload_overrides);
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're doing this as a form post, instead of as plain POST payload?

Comment: You can't store a video blob in localStorage, it is only for strings

Comment: Try the [WP Extra File Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extra-file-types/) plugin to tell WP to accept other files. But this is weird because WP does accept `.mp4` files. And, for what it's worth, MediaRecorder doesn't make `video/mp4` objects except on the very latest version of Safari. It makes `video/webm` instead.

Comment: Thanks @O.Jones, .webm actually should work just fine, WordPress allows them as well. I think the issue was just that like Musa said, you can't store blobs in localStorage. So now I'm just accessing the blob directly and it works just fine.